# Confirming Taxonomy Caching is enabled with SDL Tridion 2009 Content Delivery

Tags: caching, taxonomy, tridion2009, tridion

Does anyone have any recommendation on a simple but effective method of confirming that Taxonomy Caching is functional. I'm working on a system where the cd_broker_config (Tridion 2009) had the taxonomy caching commented out.

We've now uncommented this and restarted the deployer service but is there any way I can 100% confirm caching is now taking place? Using ORACLE 11.2.0.1

Comment: I may be missing something, but how about simply monitoring the queries that are fired against the database?

Comment: This is no problem in our sandbox environment but in the higher environments becomes more of an "issue" (not least getting approval to talk to the right person and the time that can take). On reflection I suspect there's not really any better way than sticking a {SQL Equivalent of...} trace on the database but I very much doubt this will be permitted in the Production environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the [Tridion World](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/analyzing_object_cache.aspx) article about analysing the object cache not help?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you publish your taxonomy, load a page that queries it, then turn of the Cache Channel Service (CCS) and unpublish you taxonomy the page will still work if you reload it. Then do the same with the CCS enabled and the page should fail to load the taxonomy driven parts.